# How to use 2 languages with Faker at the same time

Tags: php, laravel, faker, seeding

## Is it possible to instantiate two Faker instances with Laravel at the same time?

I want to have two fakers in a factory, one which generates english and another that generates french. They both have to be in the same factory because the database tables have english and french translations for each field.

The problem is when a new faker instance is created, the old Laravel faker's locale gets overwritten as well, making both generate French.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Model>
 */
class TestFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');
        // $faker->addProvider(new \Faker\Provider\fr_FR\Text($faker));
        return [
            'term_en' => $this->faker-> realText(200),
            'term_fr' => $faker-> realText(200),
        ];
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

This actually works, I started the question using fakers `words()` provider which only generates latin.

### EDIT #2:

There is something to be aware of, memory usage. This instantiates a faker instance every time the factory is used, this ends up slowing down mass seeding quite a bit.

Comment: `->words()` doesn't seem to be the best method of testing and recreating this issue, as it seems to output `Lorem Ipsum` text, which is neither English nor French  Sidenote, when using `Faker` for testing/seeding, does it really matter if the text is "real" English or French? In the past, when I needed to test if the correct language was being output, I'd simply use the same string, like `'Testing - EN'`, or `'Testing - FR'` (and so on for other configured languages).

Comment: Good point, with words this question does not make sense since it's only latin. When I use realText though it allows for language specific words. You are also right about it really mattering, but in this case I think it would just be nice so that when toggling the language, you will be able to tell easily even with random data.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes more sense. Been a while since I worked with `Faker`, and I couldn't remember which methods would return "real" text, figures it's the one called `realText()` ‍♂️ Anyway, I can get this to work by defining `$fakerEn = \Faker\Factory::create()` and `$fakerFr = \Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR')`, which causes `$fakerEn->realText()` and `$fakerFr->realText()` to output text in English and French respectively. I don't have a `class ... extends Factory` to do a complete test, but I suspect it has to do with using `$faker` and `$this->faker`, but I can't confirm at the moment.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. I made a mistake somewhere and thought that by calling `$fakerFr = \Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR')` it overwrote the `$this->faker` instance's locale. I thought I tried that but I guess I did not. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sweet, glad to hear thats working! Happy to help 